Chat theme accessibility issue with moderation text
While testing chat suspensions with a mod of another site, we came across an issue with our chat theme's accessibility. To improve accessibility, we should have the color of the text changed from black to white. While we usually deal with hiding plaintext, we really don't need to in this case!

Can we get the color of the text changed to white?

Is this only a dark mode issue?

@kelalaka I don't believe so. Unless dark mode is default, I don't use dark mode.
